# Execution Path for Swift Script

Tags: swift

How do I pass a path(for instance, Users/username/) to my swift script so that it always runs there(in the given path) irrespective of where the binary was downloaded(i.e. in Downloads or Desktop, etc)?

I am writing a script for the team and want to make sure it runs in the correct path no matter where its gets downloaded on their local machines.

Comment: What about having a parameter to the needed path instead, and throw an error if not present? What I did in a previous work, was to add a parameter when launching the script, if it wasn't there, "having a default" value, check for the existence of a folder/file that is needed, and if both aren't there, throw an error saying why and explaining how to put the parameter when launching thte script

Comment: okay, can you explain a little bit about  what you mean by 'a parameter when launching the script'
thank you @Larme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `yourScript`, in Terminal.app, do you more or less `$> ./yourScript`, right?

When, do you for instance a `cd`, you can do `cd ./thePathYouWant`, right? `./thePathYouWant` is a parameter (also named launch arguments or options)

In your Swift script, you can read that retrieve all the parameters with `CommandLine.arguments`.

Now, I guess that you script needs to know some folder or some file before acting.

So, in a simplified way, of launching your script like that:

`./yourScript ./Folder/File`

You can read `./Folder/File` with `CommandLine`.

Now, you can check if you find `File` at that path.

The whole logic could be in pseudo code:

```
// Parameter Path was provided, and is "correct"
if let parameterPath = parameterPath, checkExistenceOfFile(at: parameterPath) {
   //Work normally
// Parameter path was not provided or incorrect, we check if the file exists at this level
} else if checkExistenceOfFile(at: "./File") { //"./File" being the default path, we expect it to be launch at the same level
   //Work normally
// We couldn't find the path
} else {
    print("File not not found, you can execute the script like this: $>\n./yourScript ./Folder/File where "./Folder/File" is the path of the file, or execute $>./yourScript where the file is on the same folder
}
```